# Using .NET 4.0 for development server

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-4.0

My ASP.NET application runs on IIS on my web server and uses Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Beta 2.  (Its Application Pool is set to .NET Framework version `.NET Framework v4.0.21006`.)

I debug on my development machine using the ASP.NET Development Server that comes with Visual Studio.

How do I make my development machine also use .NET 4.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you just need to install .Net 4.0 on the dev machine and point your web.config to it?

Mod the Config..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0(VS.100).aspx

This should shed more light on the topic as well..

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/06/06/multi-targeting-of-web-projects-using-visual-studio-2010-beta1.aspx

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  Do I need to switch to Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 to use .NET Framework 4 Beta 2?

Comment: Was just about to answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410/can-i-develop-for-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2008