# Visual Studio 2008 support for new .NET 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008, concurrency

Will Visual Studio 2008 be supported by new .NET 4 from the get go?

I'm particularly interested in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace and the parallel task library, which I would use immediately.

Is it worth upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 when it comes out?

Comment: That would be quite restraining, don't you think? I'd rather not tie their hands by backward compatibility with older VS.

Comment: Related: *[Can I develop for .NET Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410)*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. VS2008 will not be able to target .NET 4.0:

> [...] Visual Studio 2010 supports .NET 4 and earlier projects. Visual Studio 2008 supports .NET 3.5SP1 projects.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/somasegar/visual-studio-2010-and-net-fx-4-beta-1-ships), comment posted by Polita Paulus

Comment: Thanks Michael.
I knew in my bones that an upgrade was needed, but wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 12):

While you can't use .NET 4.0 itself from VS2008, if you're interested in the Parallel Extensions stuff, you could download the [Reactive Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) (formerly LINQ to Rx) which I believe contains at least a lot of Parallel Extensions backported to .NET 3.5 SP1.

From the [Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/rxteam/archive/2009/12/22/release-notes.aspx), it includes:

> System.Threading, backport of Parallel Extensions for .NET 4 to .NET 3.5 SP1
>
> - Task for executing asynchronous operations.
> - Concurrent Collections such as ConcurrentStack, ConcurentQueue ad ConcurrentDictionary.
> - PLINQ for writing parallel queries.
> - addition Threading operations such as Barrier,SpinLock and SpinWait.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know whether upgrading to VS 2010 will be worth it, then download beta 2 now, and try it out. Run it in a virtual machine if you don't trust it on a normal development machine. Run through some of the PDC videos showing the new features. Go through the [Training Courses](http://services.social.microsoft.com/feeds/FeedItem?feedId=0afbd18c-7f2b-4b2d-aa91-24877f3f557a&itemId=7bb5e59d-8aa4-4331-9fe5-4f38f0421715&title=Visual+Studio+2010+Training+Course+on+Channel+9&uri=http%3a%2f%2fchannel9.msdn.com%2flearn%2fcourses%2fVS2010%2f&k=NvQeOSsA6StO0I4hWpAhUNDOtadLoUzzATvnA9Z389I%3d).

And above all, tell Microsoft what you think.

Comment: Hi John, I was wanting confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Historically - No.

Starting with 2008 the IDE has been able to target lower version frameworks, but I doubt they will ever target a newer version framework.