# Can Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express be used with .NET 4?

Tags: c#

I only have 512MB RAM and found out that MSVC++ 2010 Express ran hellishly slow, so I uninstalled it. Assuming same for MSVC#.
I'm planning to learn C# over the summer with the book "Pro C# and the .NET 4 platform". So I'm wondering if I can use the 2008 version?

Comment: Not that it helps, but RAM may not be as big a problem as your graphics card. Hardware acceleration would lift a huge burden off your CPU and RAM.

Comment: Also, your question is essentially identical to [998090](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998090/can-i-use-net-4-0-beta-in-visual-studio-2008) and [1986287](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986287/visual-studio-2008-support-for-new-net-4).

Comment: ah sorry v___v. i didn't search well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need Visual Studio. All you need is the [framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7&displaylang=en) (apparently they no longer call it the SDK). However, Visual Studio provides a number of nice features, but strictly speaking it isn't mandatory.

For an alternative IDE check [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/). I have very limited experience with it myself, so I can't really give you any useful pointers.

Comment: >_< I hadn't thought of that. I search for some other lightweight IDE... or just Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't use 2008 for .NET 4 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 only does .NET 3.5 and earlier.  MS doesn't retrofit new versions of the runtime / language features into older compilers.  So, you're stuck with 2010 if you want to do .NET 4.

Comment: Aw. Then is there any drawback to start learning with .NET 3.5? I already have access to the .NET 3.5 edition of the mentioned book.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to develop with .NET is the SDK and a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a fun aside, consider trying [Compilr.com](http://compilr.com) for online development of C# applications.

[alt text http://compilr.com/images/stories/compilralpha/main.jpg](http://compilr.com/images/stories/compilralpha/main.jpg)