# can I use .NET Framework 4.0 with VS2008?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

can I use .net framework 4.0 in VS2008 ? If yes how can I do that? My application uses 2.0 ,Or are there advantages to updating to the latest .NET 4.0 now? And also I came across some new features in framework 4.0 like :

```
Response.RiderectPermanent
Response.RiderectToRoute
Response.RiderectToRoutePermanent
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410/can-i-develop-for-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: Thank you , ScottGu's Blog is good and also the best answer for my question.Sorry guyz for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can upgrade your VS2008 to VS2010 for free till April, 30th, if you have premium MSDN subsription.

Answer (score 1):

You need VS2010.

Comment: so there is no way out or may be in future ?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you need [visual studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx) for .Net 4.0

Comment: yes , sure I do need VS2010. But I would be more happier if i could use .Net 4.0 with my current application.

Comment: ask the same question to Microsoft :)