# Visual Studio version and .NET target version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version

I use VS 2005 and .NET 2.0 SP 2.

If I install VS 2008 and .NET 4 on the same machine, without uninstalling VS 2005, and I keep using VS 2005 to build some applications, will these applications keep targeting .NET 2.0, or they will require .net 4.0?

I have read that with VS 2008 it is possible to choose which .NET version to target, but what about VS 2005?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 cannot target .NET Framework 4.0. VS2008 requires you install .NET Framework 3.5. Visual Studio 2005 has no support for targeting a specific .NET Framework. When it was release there wasn't a reason to introduce that capability.  If you do not have VS2010 there isn't a reason to install .NET Framework as a developer since you won't be able to target that version.

Comment: @Ramhound aparently you can "target" higher versions of .net framework in Visual Studio 2005: http://geekswithblogs.net/cyoung/archive/2007/12/01/117279.aspx

Comment: @BDN - I don't agree with that statement.  While VS05 can compile against .NET 3.5SP1 the IDE provides no way of making it target a specific framework.  If he install VS08 there is no reason to use VS05 since you CAN target VS08 projects to the .NET Framework 2.0/3.0

Comment: Related: *[Can I develop for .NET Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple major versions of .NET Framework installed and you can target any of them in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010, just go to Project's `Property Pages > Build > Target Framework` or `Properties > Application > Target Framework` (depending on project type) to pick one.

EDIT: The above function is not available in VS2005 and it will target **.NET 2.0** by default. To use it with other versions of framework, you'd need to fiddle with references a bit (i.e. replacing .net 2.0 dlls with other version's dlls).

Comment: Wrong, VS2005 doesn't have such option

Comment: I have VS2005 and 2008 (and soon 2010) without any issues. Just make sure you target the correct Framework when creating new projects.

Comment: That option is not available on VS2005. So I wonder wich version will it target: 2.0 or the latest installed on my machine?

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 can only build .NET Framework 2.0 applications.  The VS2005 installer forces you to install the .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer. @Martín VS2005 will use .NET 2.0 by default.

Answer (score 2):

Bad Display Name has not actually helped the author.

He fails to mention the following from the very article he quoted in his comment to me.

> Yes, that's to be expected I'm afraid.
>   Installing .NET 3.5 doesn't upgrade
>   the compilers you get with Visual
>   Studio 2005. You have to get VS 2008
>   if you want to use the new C# or
>   VB.NET syntax. I mentioned this
>   absence of compiler support in the
>   article.
>
> There is, of course, a distinction
>   between sytax that is understood by a
>   compiler, and the underlying libraries
>   and types that the syntax expolits.
>   You still have full access to Linq
>   technologies, but you have to write
>   code using 'standard' syntax.
>
> Here is the above code (plus some
>   additional code to print out the
>   results) written 'long-hand'. This
>   compiles in VS 2005. You need to give
>   your project a reference to
>   System.Core v3.5 and import the
>   System.Linq namespace.
>
> int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6,
>   7, 2, 0 };
>
> //var numsPlusOne = from n in numbers
>   select n + 1; IEnumerable
>   numsPlusOne = Enumerable.Select(numbers, delegate(int n) { return
>   n + 1; });
>
> foreach (int nNew in numsPlusOne) {
>   Console.WriteLine(nNew); }
>
> OK, my blog is clearly leading to
>   misunderstandings, and I need to
>   carefully qualify what is going on
>   here. People need to make a very clear
>   distinction in their minds between
>   different things:
>
> a) The .NET Framework The framework is
>   chiefly composed of a library of
>   pre-written object orientated code
>   -i.e., a class library, or perhaps more accurately, a set of libraries.
>
> b) The C# and VB.NET compilers These
>   are written as .Net assemblies. The
>   new compilers are bundled with the
>   framework.
>
> c) The C# and VB.NET editing and
>   compilation support provided in Visual
>   Studio. Starting with Visual Studio
>   2008, Microsoft has enhanced these
>   tools so that you can easily target
>   different versions of the framework.
>   This includes targeting different
>   versions of the C# and VB.NET
>   compilers.
>
> Note the following points:
>
> • All .NET 3.5 code complies with the
>   standardised definitions for version
>   2.0 of the Common Language Runtime. This includes all the code in the
>   class libraries, including Linq, and
>   even the code in the compiler
>   assemblies. Hence, Visual Studio 2005
>   can access any public members of any
>   public classes anywhere in the
>   library, and can even reach protected
>   and private members via reflection.
>   This is why you can happily exploit
>   WCF 3.5 within Visual Studio 2005.
>
> • Visual Studio 2005 predates .NET 3.5
>   and therefore its code editing and
>   compilation features do not target or
>   support the versions of the compilers
>   provided with .NET 3.5. Hence, there
>   is no support for new syntax supported
>   by the latest compilers, which is why
>   Chris' code won't compile (it uses the
>   new object initializer syntax).
>
> Syntax supported in a compiler is one
>   thing. The underlying classes and
>   other types exploited by specialised
>   syntax such as Linq are something
>   different. You don't have the ability
>   to use the new Linq syntax in the old
>   version of Visual Studio. You do,
>   however, have the ability to access
>   the underlying class libraries
>   directly using 'traditional' syntax.
>
> Having said all this, I could be
>   irresponsible and point out that
>   Microsoft did release some Linq CTP
>   tooling for Visual Studio 2005. This
>   is still available at:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1e902c21-340c-4d13-9f04-70eb5e3dceea&displaylang=en.
>
> It may be possible to use this in
>   conjunction with careful changes to
>   Microsoft.CSharp.targets referenced in
>   the MSBuild script contained in your
>   project files in order to convince
>   Visual Studio 2005 to support the
>   latest syntax and compilers. I
>   wouldn't recommend this, as this
>   depends on CTP code, which may not
>   offer complete support for the syntax
>   supported in the release version of
>   Visual Studio 2008, and a degree of
>   black-belt manipulation of the
>   mechanics of Visual Studio. I take no
>   responsibility for any problems people
>   might encounter if they try to get
>   this to work!

In other words the author of the article suggested what amounts to be a hack, the ide will not check your syntax, and you won't be able to implement any C# 3.5 syntax changes within VS05.