# Regex Class - Assembly Reference Missing?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.5

I'm defining a new class. Two issues:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Gives this error: "No overload for method 'Match' takes 4 arguments". But the MSDN defines this with 4 args.

```
catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
```

Gives this error: "The type or namespace name 'RegexMatchTimeoutException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

My using directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

I'm running VS2008Express with .NET4.5

Comment: VS2008 doesn't support .NET 4.5. It supports only up to .NET 3.5. And `Match` with timeout argument (4th) was introduced only in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of `Match` method which takes 4 arguments was only introduced in .NET 4.5. The problem is, you can not use Visual Studio 2008 to develop .NET 4 and later apps. See [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx):

> There isn't any way to target .NET 4
>   from VS08 and use new features. Having
>   said that, .NET4 is upwards comaptible
>   with .NET 3.5 - so applications you
>   build targeting .NET 3.5 with VS08
>   should work fine on top of .NET 4.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410/can-i-develop-for-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2008?lq=1).

Comment: So it looks like I need to go to VS2012 to target .NET 4.5.

Comment: That's right. [MSDN discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ab8782d-36f5-4b7a-a264-c68f2dd564f9/targeting-net-45-with-visual-studio-2010)