# whats the difference between WPF 3.5 and 4.0?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, expression-blend

i have Expression studio 3.0 and VS 2008 and VS 2010. next week i need to give my latop for repair for a month (due to shipping to Singapore) so due to performance issues i wouldn't be able use current VS 2010 in my old P4 2.8GHZ system. So i have to move back to VS 2008 and Expression blend 3.

At teh moment most apps i develop is using framework 4.0. So there is no big difference either i use VS 2008 or 2010. But recently i moved to WPF. so far learning WPF 4.0. So if im to do development with VS 2008 i would be doing it with framework 3.5 which has WPF 3 in it.

I just want to know what is the difference between WPF 4.0 and 3.0?

thanks

Comment: you can find new features of WPF 4.0 on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb613588(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your place, I would not move from `.NET 4.0 WPF` on `.NET 3.5 WPF` without *good* reason. While studying the WPF, have met bugs, which was pretty much in .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 but were successfully corrected in .NET 4.0 (all bugs will not show, you can search in the internet). In addition has been significantly improved productivity of WPF applications, in particular working with graphics. If possible, it is better to use WPF in `.NET 3.5 SP1`, more information here:

[`What’s New for Performance in WPF in .Net 3.5 SP1`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/05/15/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible write framework 4 code in VS 2008? So i can write WPF 4 code from VS 2008?

Comment: @Phill Greggan: Unfortunately, no. See [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836410/can-i-develop-for-net-framework-4-in-visual-studio-2008) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You may check the [What's New in WPF Version 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb613588(v=vs.100).aspx)

> In 3.5, the binding would write a new value back to the source after
>   each keystroke, without changing the TextBox text. But that text might
>   not represent the source's value accurately, perhaps because it
>   doesn't include formatting and conversion, or because the source
>   changed the value (in the property-setter) to something else. This led
>   to frequent and vehement complaints - people wanted the TextBox to
>   show the source's value, exactly as a TextBlock would if bound to the
>   same property with the same converters and formatting. The UI should
>   display what's actually in the data, not what the end-user typed.
>
> To fix this class of bugs in 4.0, the binding now applies formatting
>   and conversion to the source's new value after every update.
>   (LostFocus bindings already did this in 3.5.) The TextBox now shows
>   what's in the data, but that can make the user's typing more complex.

Comment: So there are complexity that adds up when rolling back tp WPF 3... finally are theses complexities minor or major?