# I am getting some error while opening Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.What should I do?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNufx.png) I'm getting this error when I open Visual Studio 2008.

> Warning    1 :The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.    ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Step 1: *read the error message*. Step 2: *do what it says*.

Comment: I don't understand what it says.

Comment: @raghav I think you should install `.NET 4.0` since you are opening a project which is built under `.NET 4.0 framework`. Go to `Control Panel` and check if you have install it.

Comment: It is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: Check if you have Net Framework 3.5, 4.0, or 4.5 installed.  Then compile with appropriate version of net installed (project properties).  You can find version of net in the list of installed application.  Easy way is to get list of programs to uninstall.

Comment: When I try to install Framework 4.0,its throwing an error saying its already installed.What should I do now? @TonyWu

Comment: @raghav Ohhhhh.... Sorry, I think you need to install newer version of visual studio...http://stackoverflow.com/a/1836420/2884831

Comment: Sorry I am using Visual Studio 2010 only @TonyWu

Comment: @raghav Topic: I am getting some error while opening `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008`.What should I do?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake only.I have changed it now.

Comment: You are opening a solution or project with double click on it. Don't you?

Comment: What is the default program for that?

Comment: Yes.I click on new project and select console application.Its starting with the main but it shows warnings as I've said before.

Comment: I have put an image of it.Click on that image. @TonyWu

Comment: @raghav I am not sure vs 2010 `EXPRESS` support .NET 4.0 or not. Would you mind to check it this way? follow the steps in the link and see whether you can put 4.0 in your target framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: @raghav I just noticed that it is just a warning......Not an error....

Comment: Can I uninstall and install it again @TonyWu

Comment: @raghav yes, you should install again but not express version

Comment: Please provide the correct link to install @TonyWu